# Understanding a function of PHP

Tags: php

I have a php script in the script I need to understand some code. Can you please guide me to understand the code: 
Here is the function from the PHP script:

```
function get_list_ip($ip_addr_cidr){
    $ip_arr = explode("/", $ip_addr_cidr);    
    $bin = "";

    for($i=1;$i<=32;$i++) {
        $bin .= $ip_arr[1] >= $i ? '1' : '0';   
    }

    $ip_arr[1] = bindec($bin);
    $ip = ip2long($ip_arr[0]);
    $nm = $ip_arr[1];
    $nw = ($ip & $nm);
    $bc = $nw | ~$nm;
    $bc_long = ip2long(long2ip($bc));

    for($zm=1;($nw + $zm)<=($bc_long - 1);$zm++)
    {
        $ret[]=long2ip($nw + $zm);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Here is the line I need to understand:

1. `$bin .= $ip_arr[1] >= $i ? '1' : '0';`  what is mean by `>=`, `?` and `:` here
2. `$nw = ($ip & $nm);`  what is `&` in variable
3. `$bc = $nw | ~$nm;` what is `|` here

Comment: See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 1):

**Ternary operator**

`$bin .= $ip_arr[1] >= $i ? '1' : '0'`

This shorthand comparisons is just another style of writing `if` conditions.

This is equivalent to:

```
if($ip_arr[1] >= $i){
   $bin .= '1';
} else {
    $bin .= '0';
}
```

**Bitwise Operators**

`|` is called `OR`

`$a | $b`: Bits that are set in either `$a` or `$b` are set.

`&` is called `AND`

`$a & $b`: Bits that are set in both `$a` and `$b` are set.

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)